# entity framework dbcontext.SaveChanges() gives divide by zero error

Tags: entity-framework

I fear I am missing the obvious. The code below produces a divide by zero error on the SaveChanges(). I have searched almost everywhere for the possible cause of this, and I can't find it.  Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

```
Public Sub AddDetailRecords()
    Dim products As List(Of Product)

    'code that builds a list of products

    For Each prd In products
        Dim eqDetail As New EmployeeQuoteDetail
        Dim rateRec As Rate = RateRecord(prd)

        eqDetail = DetailRecordForProduct(prd, eqDetail)
        eqDetail.netRate = rateRec.rate1
        eqDetail.ratePer = rateRec.ratePer

        db.EmployeeQuoteDetail.Add(eqDetail)
    Next
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

Comment: any computed fields on the db?

Comment: no, it is really basic

Comment: oops ... Yes there was.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the computed fields can be the root cause of `DivideByZeroException` exception you are seeing during DB commit performed by entity framework. Please ensure any such field doesn't result in an expression which will result in a divide by zero scenario. You should be good after that.